# Porting configuration options from netcoreapp1.1 to netcoreapp2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-configuration

In netcoreapp1.1 my config was defined in the `Startup`, which had this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  _configuration = 
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
}

private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddOptions();
  services.Configure<Stuff1>(_configuration.GetSection("stuff1"));
  services.Configure<Stuff2>(_configuration.GetSection("stuff2"));

  services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),    
  );
}
```

But in netcoreapp2.0 config is defined separately in `Program`. So `Startup` now only has this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var configuration = //???   how do I get this?

  services.AddOptions();
  services.Configure<Stuff1>(configuration.GetSection("stuff1"));
  services.Configure<Stuff2>(configuration.GetSection("stuff2"));

  services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),    
  );
}
```

So how do I get the `IConfigurationRoot` in `ConfigureServices()`, so that I can setup my strongly typed `Stuff1` and `Stuff2` options, and other stuff like the connections string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's automatically registered with the container, and is available like this:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
```

This works for me, but I think it's also possible to use `IConfigurationRoot`.